# Java3d on Eclipse(OSX Lion) access restriction

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-3d

Hi I'm getting the following error:

Access restriction: The type MainFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library /System/Library/Java/Extensions/j3dutils.jar

when im trying to import following:

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;

How do I lift off this restriction or what should I do?

I'm using eclipse on Mac OSX Lion

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These threads might be helpful:

- Java3d 1.5.2 on Macos : http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9254447
- Java3D + Newer Eclipse Version : http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2133747&tstart=0

Since Eclipse 3.6.2 this issue should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fixed on Eclipse 4.2. (I have no idea if this is actually an Eclipse issue or what)